# Get Questions if Not Answered

Tags: mysql

Basically, there are three tables with the following structure

First table: tournament_questions, having all the questions

```
id tournament_id    question     active   created_at          updated_at
 1         5       Text question    1   2018-12-08 20:28:49     NULL
```

Second table: tournament_options, having all the options

```
id  question_id option  correct active  created_at           updated_at
1      1         1       1       1     2018-12-08 20:29:02     NULL
2      1        26       0       1     2018-12-08 20:29:02     NULL
```

Third Table: tournament_user_answers, having all the user answers.

```
id  option_id   user_id score   active  created_at  updated_at
```

This table has no data at this time.

I want to achieve all the questions that are not answered by the users and hence the query should return the first question. Here is the query that I tried, but it always returns `null`

```
SELECT * FROM tournament_user_answers 
INNER JOIN tournament_options ON tournament_user_answers.option_id = 
tournament_options.id AND tournament_options.active = 1
LEFT JOIN tournament_questions ON tournament_questions.id = 
tournament_options.question_id AND tournament_questions.active = 1 
WHERE tournament_questions.tournament_id = 5 AND  
tournament_questions.active = 1 
AND tournament_questions.id IS NULL AND tournament_user_answers.user_id = 1
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with `FROM tournament_user_answers` (which is empty) and you do a `LEFT JOIN` which includes all rows on the left hand (which was empty) and appending on those the data on the right hand if available. `empty LEFT JOIN data` will be empty.

```
SELECT 
    tournament_questions.*
FROM tournament_questions
JOIN tournament_options 
    ON tournament_options.question_id = tournament_questions.id
    AND tournament_options.active = 1
LEFT JOIN tournament_user_answers 
    ON tournament_user_answers.option_id = tournament_options.id
    AND tournament_user_answers.user_id = 1
WHERE
    tournament_questions.tournament_id = 5 
    AND tournament_questions.active = 1 
GROUP BY tournament_questions.id
HAVING MAX(tournament_user_answers.id) IS NULL
ORDER BY tournament_questions.id ASC
```

In this case the left part (questions + options) has data, and the answers are appended if available. By including a `MAX(tournament_user_answers.id) IS NULL` in your `HAVING` you get all questions where there is NO answer.

Comment: Thanks Peter for your input, but the query is not giving the result. It returns no questions, but since no answer has been provided by user, then the first question should be there.

Comment: Thanks, Peter for the solution, added the active column for user_ansers and it is no working fine. Thanks!

Comment: Just a quick question, can we get the all the options for a particular question, using the same above query, and the option name and option id are placed in two new columns and separated by comma, using group coalesce or something similar?

Comment: Yes, add a [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) in your `SELECT`-part. E.g. `GROUP_CONCAT(tournament_options.id) AS optionIds`

Comment: Yup, that works as well. Any chance to get the options in random order too. Already using ORDER BY rand() and getting the questions in random order.

Comment: Any chance to read the documentation of group_concat? (Link provided in previous comment)

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would work for your case (reduced version):

```
SELECT q.id, q.question, ua.id ua_id FROM tournament_questions q
INNER JOIN tournament_options o ON q.id = o.question_id
LEFT JOIN tournament_user_answers ua ON o.id = ua.option_id
GROUP BY q.id
HAVING ua_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks Steve for your input, but the query returns the question even it is already answered. The requirement is to get the question that is not answered by that particular user under a particular tournament.